# Solve ODE of plane pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have seen in a book this system of ode's:

$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x =y\\
\dot y=-\sin x
\end{cases}
$$
and the say that the solution is
$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=\pm 2\arctan(\sinh(t))
\\y(t)=\pm 2\,\textrm{sech}(t)
\end{cases}
$$
I wonder if anyone has any hint on how this solution is found.

Comment: @Amzoti Guckenheimer and Holmes "Nonlinear Oscillations, Dynamical Systems, and Bifurcations of Vector Fields", page 201.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is
$$
\ddot x+\sin x=0.
$$
You have
$$
\ddot x \dot x+\sin x\dot x=0\implies \frac{\dot x^2}{2}-\cos x=C\implies \dot x=\pm\sqrt{C+\cos x}\,.
$$
The last is a separable equation, which can be solved explicitly in elementary functions only if the constant is $C=1$, for which you get (after integration) your answer.